# Car-lease-demo in local development environment

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The Car-Lease-Demo seems to be a perfect demo to understand Hyperledger Fabric. However, it seems to be configured to run in IBM Cloud, is anyone successful in running it locally?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you are referring to [this](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo) demo. I have not tried this, but it should be possible to run all of this on your laptop. First, follow the directions for running one or more peer instances (and a CA) [here](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev-setup/devnet-setup/). Then, you should be able to run the demo server after a few tweaks.

Looking at the code, you'd have to set some environment variables (VCAP_APP_HOST and VCAP_APP_PORT) to run the node app locally, as these will not be provided unless running in a Cloud Foundry environment.

Further, you'll need to change Server_Side/configurations/configuration.js to provide appropriate values for config.api_* as those values are also specific to the IBM Blockchain service running in Bluemix.

Comment: That is the app I was refering to. I did few tweaks,but could not able to get it running. I have trouble with the CA server itself. The request fails with some certificate error.

Comment: can you provide specifics of the error you are seeing?

Comment: Thanks @christo4ferris. I will lookup again and post the details

Comment: { OK: 'Login successful for user \'DVLA\'.' }
E0714 23:05:29.152000000  6264 tcp_client_windows.c:106] on_connect error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

E0714 23:05:29.154000000  6264 ssl_transport_security.c:877] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
E0714 23:05:29.154000000  6264 handshake.c:241] Handshake failed with error TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE
E0714 23:05:29.154000000  6264 secure_channel_create.c:102] Secure handshake failed with error 1.

@chirsto4ferris

Comment: you are running windows? which version? are you running the fabric in the vagrant development environment?

Comment: Windows 7, Vagrant environment is where I am running it